# How to configure 2.1 speakers?

Tags: 14.04, pulseaudio, speakers

I have a 2.1 speakers system that was working fine on Windows 7.

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and now just the front-left and front-right speakers are working. The subwoofer is not working.

In the Sound Settings, there is just one option: "Analog Output (Built-in Audio)" where the subwoofer control is disabled and in the "Test sound" window I can only see "Front left" and "Front right" speakers.

I have already tried:

**1) /etc/pulse/daemon.conf**

```
enable-lfe-remixing = yes
default-sample-channels = 3
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe
```

Result: no changes

**2) /etc/pulse/default.pa**

```
load-module module-combine channels=3 channel_map=front-left,front-right,lfe
```

**/etc/pulse/daemon.conf**

```
enable-lfe-remixing = yes
```

Result: another option appeared in the Sound Settings: "*Simultaneous output to Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Seris] Digital Stereo (HDMI), Buil-in Audio Analog Stereo*". Within it, when I clicked "Test Sound", a new option appeared - "Subwoofer". But the sound was played by the 2 front speakers, and the subwoofer is still not working.

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
resample-method = speex-float-1
enable-remixing = yes

enable-lfe-remixing = yes
```

Comment: can you please explain your answer a bit?